# Missing geneology names

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, genealogy

In the beginning of Parshat Korach, the posuk reads

> וַיִּקַּ֣ח קֹ֔רַח בֶּן־יִצְהָ֥ר בֶּן־קְהָ֖ת בֶּן־לֵוִ֑י וְדָתָ֨ן וַאֲבִירָ֜ם בְּנֵ֧י אֱלִיאָ֛ב וְא֥וֹן בֶּן־פֶּ֖לֶת בְּנֵ֥י רְאוּבֵֽן

The lineage of Korach is given straight back to Levi (Yitzhar, K'hat, Levi). Rashi explains that the lineage stopped with Levi so as not to include Ya'akov:

> It does not, however, make mention of Levi being “the son of Jacob”, because he (Jacob) offered prayer for himself that his name should not be mentioned in connection with their (the Korahites') quarrels

So not being listed in geneology is for the benefit of the unlisted person.

The lineage of Datan and Aviram is even more incomplete. They are listed as children of Nemu'el, from Reu'vein. Palu, their grandfather (who would be between Eli'av and Re'uvein, as per Bam 26:7) is not listed.

On is then mentioned as the son of Pelet but Pelet isn't even listed among any of the family trees of Re'uvein that I found, so not only is the connection to the tribe not confirmed, but the family member listed (Pelet) isn't connected at all. (yes, according to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50684/what-happened-to-korachs-third-co-conspirator), he absented himself later, but that doesn't clear up his lineage)

First, if anyone can find other mentions of Pelet to figure out whose Re'uvein family he is from, that would be appreciated.

Second, if Rashi explains why Ya'akov isn't listed, does anyone explain why the missing generations in the families of On and Datan and Aviram are not mentioned? Did they have a special z'chut so as not to be associated, parallel to Ya'akov's request?